# Convert model averaging results from MuMin to plot in visreg or effects packages

Tags: mumin, visreg

I'm using `MuMin` to perform model averaging using `glmmTMB` to build the global model, which all works fine.

I would then like to produce effect displays of results using the `visreg` or `effects` package. Both of these work fine on regular models produced using `glmmTMB` but not with the results of model averaging.

I appreciate the output from `avg.model` in `MuMin` is a list of component models and coefficients, which isn't compatible with `visreg` or `effects`. I've tried taking a summary of the averaged model, which looks more like the regular output from `glmmTMB` but that doesn't work either:

`mysum<- summary(avg.model)`

I was therefore wondering if there's any way to convert, reformat or otherwise produce output from an averaged model into an equivalent `glmmTMB` format that is compatible with packages such as `visreg` etc.?

I'm not sure if this can be done but, if not, it's a pity that output from model averaging can't somehow be used with packages that accept output from regular glmm's, glm's etc.
Any help or ideas appreciated!
Thanks,
Rich

PS Sorry if this is in the wrong forum, it felt more like software than stats.